# Get different rows

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5

I have two tables:

- `bookings(id,lessons_id,user_id,permit_id)`
- `lessons(id,name,date)`

I need to select all the lessons where the `user_id <>$user`

I have done the following but it's not quite correct.

```
$user = Auth::id();
            $lesson = DB::table('lessons')
        ->whereNotExists(function ($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                  ->from('bookings')
                  ->whereRaw('bookings.lessons_id', '=', 'lessons.id')
                   ->where('  bookings.user_id',' <>', '$user');
        })

            ->get();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not quite correct"?

Comment: I can't see the number `2` anywhere in your code.

Comment: @Binarus q just updated

Comment: I asked you to paste the raw MySQL query you want.  Instead, you changed your original PHP code to my answer, which isn't what actually happened here.  Don't do that.

Comment: Please clear your question bit more

Comment: I need to select all the lessons where the user_id <>$user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `whereNotExists` function:

```
DB::table('lessons')
    ->whereNotExists(function ($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw(1))
              ->from('bookings')
              ->whereRaw('bookings.lessons_id = lessons.id AND
                  bookings.user_id = ?', [$user]);
    })
->get();
```

This would correspond to the following raw MySQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM lessons t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM bookings b
                  WHERE b.lessons_id = t.id AND b.user_id = 2);
```

Comment: bookings.user_id <> Auth::user()->id; gives me a syntax error how can i write this

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  Do you get an exact error using my answer?

Comment: I am trying to make the ->whereRaw('bookings.lessons_id = lessons.id AND
                  bookings.user_id = 2'); different from current user id =>bookings.user_id <> Auth::user()->id

Comment: simply make the bookings.user_id different from current user id

Comment: Tim help till the end ->where('bookings.lessons_id' ,'=',' Lessons.id')
  ->where('bookings.user_id','=',Auth::id()); this gives me a cardinality error

Comment: I don't know your code, so I can't offer much help.  Your two WHERE clauses won't give you the right output, and it doesn't match the raw EXISTS query I gave above.

Comment: Tim simply make the bookings.user_id different from current authenticated user id

Comment: please I need this

Comment: I can't help beyond what I've already done.  You need a Laravel/Eloquent expert, which I am not.

Comment: Tim $user = Auth::user()->id; now simply make the bookings.user_id  different from $user

Comment: Take my raw query and edit it with your new logic.  Then update your question with that query.  I can't read your mind.

Comment: TAke a look please

Comment: James, check my updated answer.  Use a positional parameter `?` in the raw `WHERE` clause, then bind `$user` to it.  I think this should work.

Comment: @JamesMoore Try putting `$user` into an array.  I rejected your edit because you used a completely raw query, which is prone to SQL injection.  You need to figure out how to bind that user parameter.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong.  The documentation supports the syntax I used.  My guess is that your code has a problem which you can't see.  Maybe it has nothing to do with this.

Comment: I dont think so the raw query worked plus its only this in my code

Comment: Then use the raw query for now and come back to this when you have time later.